Should hard-problem be made a synonym of hardness-assumption?
Should the tags hard-problem and hardness-assumption be merged or be made synonyms of each other? They are both used for the exact same things (cryptographic hardness assumptions).

There is also the option to merge and make it a synonym by the way. This one may require some research on how they are used. Good catch, I'm thinking on how to resolve it.

Um, does anybody else have an opinion on this, because I'm still thinking on it now and then and drawing a blank. We cannot make both terms synonyms by the way, that last sentence would favor "hardness-assumption" it seems...

@MaartenBodewes why can't we make hard-problem a synonym of hardness-assumptions?

After checking the tagged questions most of them are either really about hardness assumptions or try to introduce a new one.

OK, so make hard problem a synonym of the master hardness-assumption? Seems reasonable to me.

hard-problem has been merged into hardness-assumptions.
